# html/template: optional outer element around sub-template if it's not empty

Tags: go

I have a template with an inner content template and I want to render it in a way that there is an outer wrapping element around inner content which is only shown if the content is not empty.

For example:

```
...
{{if template-content-exists-and-not-blank}}
  <div class="content">
   {{template "content" .}}
  </div>
{{end}}
...
```

I want to render `<div>` only when the result of `{{template "content" .}}` is not empty. I don't want to put the enclosing `<div>` into content, as it doesn't really belong there, and it will be duplicated across all content sub-templates.

1. I cannot use `{{template ...}}` as a function argument, so it's not possible to test it.
2. I wrote a custom `defined` boolean function that tests if a sub-template is defined, but the `content` template is executed regardless of whether it's true or false (no short-circuiting), and obviously fails if it's not defined.

   ```
   t.Funcs(
       html.FuncMap{
           "defined": func(name string) bool {
               return t.Lookup(name) != nil
           },
       },
   )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do one of two things:

1. Put the containing tag in the sub-template
2. Pre-render the sub-template and pass it to the outer template as a string